# How to open ViewSonic VX3276-2K-mhd?

Tags: display, repair, disassembly

I have a slim ViewSonic monitor and yesterday noticed that there’s a spot dimmer.

After searching the internet I found out that it could be simply a cable not fully plugged.

The thing is that I remove the bottom screws and I can’t open it.

Does anyone know how to open this kind on slim monitors?

Thanks!

Comment: There will likely be clips, and possibly even glue. You'll need spudgers or small wedge tools to carefully pry the edges apart.